# Can someone help me understand proof that "a sphere is connected"

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, proof-explanation

The question is to prove

> Prove $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1\}$ is connected.

The answer provided as:

> The sphere can be represented as a union of meridians (each of which is homeomorphic to a closed interval and therefore connected); the meridians all go through the North pole (and the South pole), thus the union is connected.

I am a bit confused because in my text it says that $S^1$ (i.e. a circle) is not homeomorphic to any interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

So suppose we treat the sphere as union of slices where each slice is a circle, then no circle is homeomorphic to the closed interval. Each closed interval is connected, and any space homeomorphic to the closed interval is connected, hence no circle is connected therefore the sphere is not connected....Not good!

Can someone help me understand this answer?

Comment: Why do you say "no circle is connected"? That is false.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Maybe you can help me with this also. The circle and the closed intervals are not homeomorphic. The closed interval $[0, 2\pi]$ is connected, then we can use map $f(x) = [cos(x), sin(x)]$ to send the closed interval to the unit circle. It is true that $f(x)$ is not a homeomorphism? Why it is that we can use this map and still preserve connectedness?

Comment: It is correct that $f$ is not a homeomorphism (it is not even injective as $f(0) = f(2\pi)$). However, the continuous image of a connected set is connected, so it follows that $S^1$, the image of the continuous function $f$, is connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_(geography)) is half of a great circle with endpoints the north and south pole. Such a thing is homeomorphic to a closed interval.

Comment: 11 seconds faster than me, and with a link.

Answer (score 3):

A meridian is a half circle, which is indeed homeomorphic to a closed interval